# Google play console no longer tests app on most devices

Tags: google-play-console

Since updating my android studio on the 15th of January 2019 the google play console is no longer testing my app on any devices other than the P8 Lite Huawei. All the other devices state "This device could not be tested at this time, please upload a new APK".

I cannot find any information anywhere as to why this is occurring. Is it due to Google no longer supporting tests on those devices? Or is it a change made to my code with the update?

I have included my gradle code in case it's due to an SDK conflict or something but frankly, I'm stumped.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.frozencodegame.evolution"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 27
    versionName "0.0027"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
aaptOptions {
    cruncherEnabled = false
}
```

Apologies, I have now included my manifest too:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.frozencodegame.evolution">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:fullBackupContent="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
    <activity
        android:name=".pages.pageSplice"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.transparentTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" />
    <activity
        android:name=".pages.pageBreed"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.transparentTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".pages.pageSettings"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.transparentTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".pages.pageCreature"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.transparentTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" />
</application>
```

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar case, although for me it's even worse. None of the devices manage to test the APK. I always get the error "This device could not be tested at this time, please upload a new APK". Have you managed to sort this out @Maxmansung ?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can see what devices your app in compatible with by using the Play Console ([help docs](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7353455))

> - Sign in to your Play Console.
> - Select an app.
> - On the left menu, click Release management > Device catalogue.
> - If you haven't already, review and accept the Terms of Service.
> - Select the All, Supported or Excluded tabs.
> - If you want to download a list of devices as a CSV file, near the right side of the page, click Download device list.

Other devices are not being stopped by Google in general. If you need more help from stackoverflow users, then the problem is usually caused by the app manifest. You may need to add your `AndroidManifest.xml` to your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Looking at the device catalogue it seems that there are no excluded devices still and that I have accepted the terms of service. I have also looked specifically at the devices that google is suggesting cannot be tested and they are all supported. I assume this means there is something I have done within my code that's preventing this?

Comment: Yeah, same problem here.. Devices how to be Supported in the Device catalogue, but in the Pre-Launch test I get the same error as the OP, and none of the Devices are testing my app now..

Comment: same here, anyone had a solution for this ?

Comment: In general you should contact Play Console support, who can look at your particular APK. The problem is likely to be different for each person